# C# Dynamic return type

Tags: c#, .net

#### I've solved my problem

```
    public virtual T GenerateCommand()
    {
        Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
        if (typeParameterType == typeof(SqlCommand))
        {
            //SqlCommand
        }
        else if (typeParameterType == typeof(MySqlCommand))
        {
            //MySqlCommand
        }

        return new T()
        {

        };
    }
```

I'm building a class that generates Queries/Commands, the class has the ability to generate various DbCommands (MsSqlServer & MySql) when the type of the database is defined in field of the class. How can I return the correct type?

I tried this:

```
public virtual DbCommand GenerateCommand()
{
    //.....
}
```

but I always need to convert the return value:

```
MySqlCommand s = this.GenerateCommand() as MySqlCommand;
```

I also tried this:

```
public virtual T GenerateCommand<T>()
{
    //.....
}
```

But it's not what I'm looking for because I cannot create an instance of DbCommand so I cannot return nothing.

Is there some way that T will be based on stored type on my class?

Edit:
the using of generic class throw two exceptions at least:

```
    if (T is MySqlCommand)
    {
        return new MySqlCommand();
    }
    else
    {
        return new SqlCommand();
    }
```

> 'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand' to 'T'

```
(T)MySqlCommand()
```

also do not work

Edit 2:
can I do something like that?

```
public virtual T GenerateCommand(SqlDatabaseKind dbKind)
{
    T = (dbKind == SqlDatabaseKind.MicrosoftSqlServer) ? SqlCommand :
        MySqlCommand;
}
```

Comment: Can you justify why avoiding the cast is worth the large hassle and risk of coming up with an alternative solution? Especially given that you don't want to use generics, which is your best bet.

Comment: Why don't you want to use generics? You can make the whole class to be a generic, regarding of what type of `DbCommand` to use.

Comment: Why do you need to cast? Doesn't DbCommand expose most of the methods that are needed in most data access scenarios?

Comment: I want the class dynamic and easy to move between the databases types.

Comment: If you solved your problem, then you should mark solution in question or answer your own question. I need to implement dynamic return type, and found this in Google, but there is no answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can have generic classes. It sounds like this is more what you are looking for. Then you can just return the type that the class was created as:

```
public class MyDatabaseClass<T> where T : DbCommand
{

    public virtual T GenerateCommand()
    {
        //.....
    }
}
```

I have used a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to make sure that the T is of type DbCommand, also.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot use this, I cannot create an instance of DbCommand so I've no way to return what I need.

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of DbCommand - You need one that inherits from it.

Comment: Bun I cannot know which inherits is defined in T

Comment: @Exsaliver: What makes you think you can't use this? It doesn't matter if you can't create an instance of a `DbCommand` (i.e., it is `abstract`), all that matters is that _a_ `DbCommand` or derived will be returned. The compiler will know what to do when you attempt to instantiate the class where `T` _is_ `DbCommand` if it was `abstract`.

Comment: @Justin: It looks like it would need an added constraint to have a parameterless constructor or similar.

Comment: @JeffMercado But I cannot know what to return, MySqlCommand Or SqlCommand.

Comment: @Exsaliver: Again, it's not going to matter, it will all be taken care of for you just by it being generic.

Comment: @JeffMercado Try it by yourself, give me an example.

Comment: @Exsaliver: Try this code: http://ideone.com/w9QpY but use Visual Studio to compile it (not Mono). As long as there's a constraint to only allow types with parameterless constructors, abstract classes will be rejected. (Mono will give a different but related error)

Comment: @JeffMercado I know that I can return interface when I use *new()* but MySql & Sql Server have different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You make 'GenerateCommand()' as a void, with two overloads:
one, which receives an 'out MySqlCommand', and another which receives an 'out SqlCommand', and change the in the function.

```
void GenerateCommand(out MySqlCommand com)
{
.
.
.
}

void GenerateCommand(out SqlCommand com)
{
.
.
.
}
```

out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: out is not for that sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move between database types, then your code should depend on abstraction (DbCommand, DbConnection, DbParameter etc) instead of concrete implementations (SqlConnection, SqlCommand). Otherwise you will have to change all database-related code when new database provider added. And you will duplicate all database-related code for every provider.

.Net already has abstract factory for creating all this database-related abstractions. It's called [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx). And looks like it's what you are trying to implement:

```
public virtual DbCommand CreateCommand()
public virtual DbConnection CreateConnection()
```

.Net has some built-in provider-specific implementations of this factory (SqlClientFactory, OleDbFactory, OdbcFactory). [Here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/08/CreatingDataAccessLayerUsingDbProviderFactoriesDbProviderFactory.aspx) you can find how to use DbProviderFactories. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216626/how-to-use-ado-net-dbproviderfactory-with-mysql) you can find DbProviderFactory for MySql.