# Setting provider and connection string in EntityFramework for MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and in my solution there are 9 projects and it will enlarge. My problem is stating connection string in .config file. When I did like this, I had to state connection string for 4-5 projects and when I wanted to change my connection, changing ConnectionStrings is becoming an obligation for 4 or 5 projects. I want to set connection string in DbContext constructor. DbContext can provide me this ability but I can't define providerName.So dbconnection of context automatically use SqlClient but I want to use MySql provider. My connection string is :

```
"Server=localhost;Database=xxx;Uid=auth_windows;Persist Security Info=True;User=root;Password=yyyyyy;"
```

Also I can't specify provider name in connection string like "Provider = MySql.Data.MySqlClient". It throws exception "Provider keyword is not supported".

I am changing my question for more comprehensible.

In short I want to to this.

```
public class XxContext : DbContext
{

       public XxContext()
       {

            this.Database.Connection.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost bla bla bla";

       }
}
```

But I don't know how to state you should use MySql.Data.MySqlClient(without config file). Is it possible ? If it is, how can I do ?

Comment: So you want to change the Provider in code or in configuration?

Comment: I want to change in code

Answer (score 4):

Yours is a [connection string used with `SqlConnection` objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since these objects support only SQL Server you cannot use the `Provider` keyword. Moreover, since you're using EF, you need to specify a different connection string in order to use the model of your database, a context and the `Provider` keyword. A typical [EF connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) would be:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;
         Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
         multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In order to use the MySQL provider, consider these steps provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20294903/702048):

> Entity Framework 6 offers some handy subtle changes which aid in both
>   getting MySQL working and also creating dynamic database connections.
>   Getting MySQL working with Entity Framework 6
>
> First, at the date of my answering this question, the only .Net
>   connector drivers compatible with EF6 is the MySQL .Net Connectior
>   6.8.1 (Beta development version) which can be found at the official MySQL website here.
>
> After installing, reference the following files from your Visual
>   Studio solution:
>
> ```
> Mysql.Data.dll
> Mysql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
> ```
>
> You will also need to copy these files somewhere where they will be
>   accessible to the project during build time, such as the bin
>   directory.
>
> Next, you need to add some items to your Web.config (or App.config if
>   on desktop based) file.
>
> A connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mysqlCon"
         connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=dbName;Uid=username;Pwd=password"

         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

> Also add the provider, inside the  and  nodes, optionally (this is an absolute must in the second part of
>   my answer, when dealing with dynamically defined databases) you may
>   change the  node:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers> </entityFramework>
```

> If you change the defaultConnectionFactory from the default sql server
>   connection, don't forget to remove the  nodes which are
>   nested in the defaultConnectionFactory node. The
>   MysqlConnectionFactory does not take any parameters for its
>   constructor and will fail if the parameters are still there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DbProviderFacory` which is registered in the config file (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216626/how-can-i-use-ado-net-dbproviderfactory-with-mysql)).

Your config file should have something like this

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
       invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
       description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
       type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

And your `DbContext` and `IDbContextFactory` implementation something like this...

**DbContext**

```
public class MyDbContext
    : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbConnection connection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {

    }
}
```

**IDbContextFactory**

```
public class MyDbContextFactory
    : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    private readonly string _connectionStringName;

    public MyDbContextFactory(string connectionStringName)
    {
        Contract.Requires<NullReferenceException>(
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionStringName),
            "connectionStringName");
        _connectionStringName = connectionStringName;
    }

    public MyDbContext Create()
    {
        var connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings[_connectionStringName];

        var connection = DbProviderFactories
            .GetFactory(connectionStringSettings.ProviderName)
            .CreateConnection();

        if (connection == null)
        {
            var message = string.Format(
                "Provider '{0}' could not be used",
                connectionStringSettings.ProviderName);
            throw new NullReferenceException(message);
        }

        connection.ConnectionString = connectionStringSettings
            .ConnectionString;
        return new MyDbContext(connection, true);
    }
}
```

A connection is given to the context constructor with is able to include the `DbProvider` programatically. The context is set to own the connection so that it can open on first use and close on dispose.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to set the provider but the easiest one I think, adding an attribute to your DbContext class. Then pass full connection string to its constructor. Construct a MySqlConnection object and pass it to DbContext constructor. See the EF6 sample code below;

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
class OrderDb : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public OrderDb(string conStr): base(new MySqlConnection(conStr), true)
    {
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the flowoin annotation to your dbcontext class :

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

change this :

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

to this :

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```